# Subs in Matlab symbolic toolbox does not evaluate values

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I try to substitute long expressions with short variables. Here I want to replace `3*b^2`with `d`. After that, I want to evaluate the expression `a` with numeric values. But somehow Matlab does not recognize if I assign a value to `b` and instead refers to the UNKNOWN variable `d`. How do I subsitute with `d` and also tell Matlab to compute `d` as a function of `b`?

```
syms a b c d
a = 3*b^2 + c;
a = subs(a, 3*b^2, d)     % substitute long term
subs(a,{b,c},{2,3})       % Returns ans = d + 3, But I want it to return ans = 15
```

Comment: After substitution of long term (3*b^2) in expression 'a' for new symbol 'd', there isn't symbol 'b' in the expression 'a' anymore, so, substitution of 'b' for value 2 in the last command, will have no effect

Comment: So does there exist any alternative to display the substituted version of the expression while keeping all initial variables?

Comment: Define a separate variable for substituted version of expression 'a': a_s = subs(a, 3*b^2, d), and use the original 'a' for numerical evaluation of the expression.